# Negative tag score

Tags: support, tag-score

I was reviewing some posts where I found [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151256/niravkumar) promoting a website and flagged his post for moderator attention and his answers got deleted. Now when I see his profile, I see negative tag scores. Is this a bug or not?

[image: Tag score]

---

The user still has negative tag scores, so, as you mentioned, the process might have failed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's not a bug. The tag score is the sum of upvotes and downvotes on answers, it can go negative (unlike reputation).

Tag scores are usually recalculated once a day (03:00 UTC), but that process sometimes fails. So the scores on that profile might stay there for a few days.

References:

- [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)
- [Tag scores are not updated and the issue is getting worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for answer and the links.The user has no posts now and he has negative tag scores which means its a bug right? Tag scores  not updated post is also tagged as a bug.

Comment: The tag scores will disappear when the tag score update thing runs successfully. The fact that that thing fails has been reported a lot (including here).